# Attempt to heartbeat failed: Multiple consumers with single rest proxy instance

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-rest

I'm playing around with Kafka topics and rest-proxy and faced a behavior I don't understand.

I have 1 zookeeper, 1 kafka broker, 1 schema registry and 1 rest-proxy instance. Then the topic with 1 partition and 2 consumers reading from it are created.

I created a topic with the following command:

```
kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --zookeeper localhost:32181 --partitions 4 --replication-factor 1 --topic my-ttopic
```

Then I tried to read from both of the consumers. Upon the second consumer is created and attempt to read using it is made some rebalancing is triggered and reading ***just hangs***. The Kafka Rest in turns produces tons of logs like this:

```
[2020-10-11 09:29:30,645] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-10-11 09:29:30,649] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-10-11 09:29:30,649] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-10-11 09:29:30,650] INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group grps in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-14) (reason: Adding new member consumer-grps-2-0b19385b-df80-4d11-8eaa-7c313354a131 with group instance id None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2020-10-10 20:44:51,713] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:44:54,726] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:44:57,739] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:00,752] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:03,766] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:06,780] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:09,793] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:12,806] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:15,818] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:18,829] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:21,841] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:24,854] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2020-10-10 20:45:27,867] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-10-10 20:45:30,880] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-10-10 20:45:33,893] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-10-10 20:45:36,905] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-grps-2, groupId=grps] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
```

Can you give any advice on what the problem might be about?